# How to return XML representation of Page<MyEntity> from Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: xml, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-boot

Given a **spring-data** repository extending `PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long>`,
I would like to return the result of the repository's method `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);` from a **spring-mvc controller** as **XML**.

The controller looks like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public HttpEntity<Page<MyEntity>> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<MyEntity> all = myEntityRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(all, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However, when calling the controller with `Accept: application/xml`, I get

> Error 406 Not Acceptable

When changing to `Accept: application/json` everything works fine.

Returning a single instance of `MyEntity` as XML also works as expected, so I'm pretty sure, it's not a problem of missing libs on the classpath.

How can I return an XML representation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create your own `Page` implementation and add JAXB annotations.

Comment: So there is no out-of-the-box support for that?

What about a `List<MyEntity>` instead of page? With Jersey or Resteasy those would be automatically marshalled to XML without any additional implementation needed.
But it seems that in Spring I have to create my own JXAB-annotated wrapper class for `List<MyEntity>`. Am I correct?

Comment: AFAIK those other frameworks just use JAXB as well. If `MyEntity` has JAXB annotations it would work with all of them (including Spring)

Comment: Using `@GET @Produces("application/xml") public List<MyEntity> getAll() {...}` works fine and out-of-the-box in jersey and resteasy - to my experience.

But not in spring, at least not if I just change the controller above to return `List<MyEntity>`.

If I want to make it work I have to create my own JAXB annotated wrapper class e.g. `MyEntityList`.